Live patch works excelently - it just shows a red ! mark on task bar
Opening the live patch does not show any error, so why the red "!" mark on the shiled icon?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I just restarted and there are no errors on apt/snap level. nor on dpkg ...
Is this the normal?

You've provided few specifics; no specifics as to Desktop or Server install (mention of icon may imply desktop, but it's better if you're specific). Ubuntu's livepatch includes specific kernels only, but you may have opted to use a kernel that isn't supported by livepatch for example, or have other issues. You could have provided a link to a screenshot for us to get a better idea, or been specific with details, especially if you explored the status (ua status etc)

Take a look at the following link (bit old 2019) which shows the correct (green tick) icon. It also has commands to determine its current status. https://www.howtogeek.com/446140/how-to-use-canonicals-livepatch-service-on-ubuntu/ Good luck with the debug.

A restart solves the red to green, and I am a big fan of suspend-resume of my machines... Would be a nice if the guys at canonical just put a tooltip to "turn off and on again" :-) always a fix...
